# Adapting Held–Karp algorithm to visit groups of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, traveling-salesman-problem

The Held–Karp algorithm has exponential time complexity $\Theta\left(2^n n^2\right)$, which is better than brute forcing the TSP which requires $\Theta(n !)$.

I'm interesting in amending the Held–Karp algorithm to determine the shortest path between each group of vertices. This is different from the TSP as it allows vertices to be travelled twice and not every vertix needs to be visited. Imagine, instead of visiting each city, visiting each country that each city is in.

I have an algorithm to brute force the solution, but this is very slow. Is it possible to adapt the Held–Karp algorithm to finding the shortest path between groups?

[image]

For example, in this weighted graph, here vertices 1 - 3 are in the red group, 4-6 in blue , 7-9 in green, and 10-12 is in purple. The shortest route is 4 <-> 10 <-> 3 <-> 7.

Comment: you can check the 1989 paper by JOHN R. CURRENT and DAVID A. SCHILLING:  "Covering Traveling Salesman" https://www.jstor.org/stable/25768381
Not sure if your problem is different; would be interesting to know in which respect.

Comment: This is the solution. I feel stupid for not finding this. Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to feel stupid; similar things happen(ed) to me, but it had the positive effect that I found solutions myself, occasionally better ones.